# How to provide a model for the entire app with ChangeNotifierProvider with access to Localizations.localeOf(context)?

Tags: flutter

In order to provide a model to the entire app I need to use a `ChangeNotifierProvider` as a parent of `MaterialApp`.

But as a parent of `MaterialApp` it can't access `Localizations.localeOf(context)` because this context needs to be from `MaterialApp` (I wonder why accessing device info needs a context but that's how it works).

So I have quite a picle here.

My model needs to load stuff considering the device's language right when it starts. If I place my `ChangeNotifierProvider` as a child of `MaterialApp` I can get the locale but I don't have access to this model if I push a view with `Navigator.push(...)`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.

I found a [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/devicelocale) to get the Language without the need of the context (the way it should be).

This way I can put my ChangeNotifierProvider as a parent of MaterialApp and everything works as expected.

I filled a feature request on Flutter to fix this need of a context to get device info. It shouldn't be necessary. If you agree with that, feel free to endorse: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44229